# Ampersand displays differently in a form than a list

Tags: javascript, forms, formatting

I have a master / detail screen where when the user clicks a record in the master list the detail is opened and written to a form for edits. When the original detail is saved to mysql it is sanitised with htmllspecialcharacters. So an ampersand looks like `&amp;` at table level.
When the data is read to the master detail page, both the list array and detail record item are created by an AJAX call that JSON  parses etc.
An ampersand looks the same, i.e. `&amp;`, in the master lists object array and the detail items object.

In the list the array is mapped to a template that inserts the elements value with modifying it.

The form is built the same way but in the list an ampersand is `&` and in the form it is `&amp;`

Anyone know what going on?
Thanks
Mark

Comment: `&amp;` in HTML will be rendered as `&` on the page.

Comment: "When the original detail is saved to mysql it is sanitised with htmllspecialcharacters." This is wrong and you should not do this. Santising should happen when outputting to the browser, not before.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you do want to sanitise the data going in the database but not as if it's HTML. You are protecting against [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) rather than XSS attacks.

Comment: I sanitise the input to avoid sql injection etc. Standard practice??

Comment: You're right, Bobby Tables sucks but what should I be doing instead of htmlspecialcharacters?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid XSS and Bobby T

Comment: Is it enough to simply be using PDO prepared statements calling stored procedures?

Comment: Yeah, prepared queries mean you don't need to sanitise database input. At all. You can insert anything.

Comment: Cool, looks like I was doing stuff a bit back to front, or even front to back... hopefully Im headed in the right direction.